# Preparation for STEP Mathematics Examinations

Tags: soft-question, advice

First I will give some background, to put my question in context.

I am currently in my final year of school, and in order to meet my university offer to study Mathematics this Autumn, I am required to sit the STEP Mathematics Exams this June. For those who don't know (which I assume will be the vast majority of people who read this), there are three STEP (stands for "Sixth Term Examination Papers") exams entitled STEP I, STEP II and STEP III respectively, each 3 hours long. STEP I,II share a common syllabus, STEP III's syllabus is broader. [See here](http://www.admissionstestingservice.org/images/47831-step-specification-rebranded-.pdf) for a detailled specification. STEP II,III are intended to be harder than STEP I. They are graded U,3,2,1,S (S being the highest). There are 13 questions, each worth 20 marks. You may pick any question you wish to answer and the best 6 solutions count towards the final mark (out of 120). Examples of STEP exams would be: [STEP I 2001](http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/STEP%20I%202001.pdf), [STEP II 2002](http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/STEP%20II%202002.pdf), [STEP III 2009](http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/STEP%20III%202009.pdf).

These examinations are used by the best UK universities (Cambridge, Warwick, Imperial, etc) for mathematics to provide a better discriminator between the ability of candidates. The reason they choose to use this exam is that A-Level Mathematics exams are more computational and do not require much mathematical thinking. In contrast, STEP exams are more proof-based, or at least closer to "real" undergraduate mathematics.

**My aims for this exam**

I am aiming to be able to write 5-6 full solutions in the 3 hours, but currently I am struggling to adapt to this more formal style of mathematics (which I appreciate is less formal than university mathematics, but the style of questions in STEP is considerably more formal than A-Level).

**My questions:**

1. Is there anything else I can do besides practising questions that will improve my ability?
2. Are there any books that you think will be particularly helpful?
3. Is there any advice that you think will be useful?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Warwick is indeed the best ;) (my old stomping ground!). I would look over old A-level papers. When I had to do that prep that was the best advice I was given..presumably you are doing the further mathematics course already? (though for some of the STEP this is not required)

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes. I have almost finished my FM syllabus. I've seen older questions in books such as "Further Pure Mathematics" by Bostock & Chandler, but I think that they are much easier than STEP.

Comment: @Chinny84 I hate it here at Warwick, I truly regret this university, the maths department is good but the uni has become horrible.

Comment: ALL THE PAST PAPERS, I went back as far as 1984, I got a 1 in step 3, 2 in 2 and 3 in 1 weirdly. I did every A-level maths module for the MEI exam board which covers the most ground (it was created because the others were failing) I recommend you do MEI FP2 and FP3 extra as these together cover a lot of content the others do not, M4 and DE are great practice

Comment: @AlecTeal I am sorry to hear that. When I was there 2003-11/12 it was pretty good (though my comment was more tongue in cheek than anything). OP, there are other books in that series? though that was my next point of call..but try searching old A-level papers themselves.

Comment: I agree with fellow posters, go to the STEP website and download all of the past papers, that's what I did and it worked a treat. I don't know the calibre of your sixth form teachers but I found that due to the complexity of the questions, it would be days before I got partial or full help from them. One of my teachers was excellent, I went to her regulalrly for help! GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Look at the past papers and do some of the questions. Keep going and be determined. Aim to solve eight questions per paper before looking at the model answers and examiners report. Read the model answers for questions you didn't do - should you have been able to do them? Or do they look like a potentially easy win if you research a less familiar field. Then read the examiners reports again - what did other people find difficult? Did you overcome the difficulty? Are you avoiding the common mistakes?

Comment: Once you have solved a question ... Go back to the beginning and write out a solution. Come back to it a week later and see if you can do the same. That helps to train you to think and write at the pace you need.

Comment: @AlecTeal Can you expand on your opinion on Warwick? (I'm not sure if this place is appropriate for discussion - is there another place on this site for talking?)

Comment: @Sigma there's a joke here among students and staff (eg porters) "Warwick PLC" everything is for money and the newer accommodations are done so cheaply they are falling apart. There's a new building that sags inwards because it was made from prefabs, staff are forced to change every 9-12 months so nothing is consistent. The vice chancellor doesn't want cars ever coming past his house so a road was re-routed, now he has decided he still wont let inbound taxis that way. They use no internal talent and actively encourage overseas students over internal ones (ones already at Warwick)

Comment: @Sigma to an extent EVERY university is a business, I get that, but Warwick is THE WORST, they will not lift a finger to help unless absolutely forced (because it is easier) and the lower ranks of staff have no say in this with horrible contracts. I honestly wish - DESPITE the maths department - I hadn't come here. Source third year who is still living on Campus.

Comment: @Sigma in my first year we had lamps and our rooms cleaned and the kitchens cleaned 3 times a week, in the second year no lamps (but conferences still had lamps!) In my third year rooms are no longer cleaned and the kitchen is done twice a day, the cleaning staff are over-worked, they provided a support for the students to (by getting to know them) now they have little time and too many.

Comment: @Sigma there was a porter that died, the university's top priority was getting his family to sign something not making them liable, I knew the guy, he was lovely but picked on by a manager constantly. I genuinely hate this place.

Comment: @Sigma I can't say much more without (potentially) identifying people that confided in me, but I hope you see my point

Comment: @alecteal it seems to have definitely turned down the wrong track. I know my research group seems to still be flourishing. But I guess the gripe is with the money spinning side of things..but whatever the case may be, remember to hang in there the rep of warwick grad in maths is still very good and go and do a phd elsewhere with that first in your pocket :).

Comment: I did my phd there also only because I throughly enjoyed my time there..societies and sport teams etc. but warwick is a bubble (as we all know that saying) but it can be isolating at the same time. If you need any other more personally discussions I have my email on my profile page :).

Comment: @Chinny84 we'll see, I'm not sure I want that any more.

Comment: @Chinny84 I don't think there are other books of similar difficulty in that series (Although the authors have published textbooks on Core Maths, Mechanics, and Statistics. I've seen a few older papers from the 70s, but still I find the questions easier than STEP. I don't think that there is much (besides Olympiads) that compares with STEP for difficulty in terms of pre-university mathematics.

Comment: I don't know too much about the British system, but an excellent book with challenging problems is *Calculus* by Michael Spivak. It is much more to do with proofs than most calculus books. It has a complete solutions manual.

Answer (score 2):

I was recommended to work through the book "How to think like a mathematician" before starting my undergrad. It focuses on the transition from high school math to university math, in particular how to write proofs. It might be helpful for you to go though it. Otherwise than that, just practise, practise, practise.

EDIT: One more thing: if there are other people you know taking the STEP papers, have a few sessions with them where you talk about your solutions and share ideas. It helps to work through the problems once on your own, and then once in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Stephen Siklos: Problems in Core Mathematics, which exists in two different editions. He used to be a STEP examiner. Also check out the MathsHelper website, which has links to these publications. Also Warwick University created a STEP course for prospective candidates, devised by one of the STEP examiners from MEI. Also check out Meikleriggs, the STEP maths website. If you can't find any of this let me know.

Comment: Here is a link to the two documents by Stephen Siklos: http://www.admissionstestingservice.org/for-test-takers/step/preparing-for-step/