# How to develop mathematical ingenuity besides practicing problems(advice for Cambridge STEP Exams)?

Tags: problem-solving, advice

I have been preparing for the STEP II and III exams administered by the University of Cambridge by solving several papers (I've done hundreds of problems).

I am quite good at interpreting and using the novel mathematics involved in the sort of questions administered in the test.

However, one place I consistently get stuck in is where there is a hidden 'trick' in the question that needs to be identified in order to proceed. I often get stuck when this happens and it takes me a long time until I get a spark of inspiration and solve the problem.

There is limited time in the STEP Exam and because of this issue, I am usually unable to complete the paper in mock exams.

After some research, the only advice I have found is to practice more. However, the questions administered are so new and don't fall into a certain class of problems that can be solved using similar methods. I feel doing more and more practice isn't helping me and only very rarely is there a similar trick involved to solve the question.

Just to clarify, I have fairly good mathematical thinking and have almost no issue in understanding and manipulating the complex maths found in STEP. My main difficulty is getting stuck when certain 'tricks' have to be used and I don't know how to identify them.

What can I do to increase my probability of these hidden 'tricks' striking me more? Is it even possible? Note that I have about 2 months remaining and don't have a very long time to improve, although I have definitely already put in more than the required effort that typical STEP candidates put in.

Also, I'm sorry for the general nature of the question but I hope you get my concern.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Very few STEP candidates can do six problems in three hours. If you're able to produce four good solutions, that's usually enough for grade 1. The more you practise, ideally not under timed conditions (i.e. persevere until you get a solution), the easier it will be in the exam to think creatively and find the ingenuity needed to solve the problems. Also, you might find Stephen Siklos's booklet has some good advice about how to approach problems.

Comment: @A.Goodier Thanks for your reply. By "four good solutions"-do you mean four complete solutions or four "partially done" solutions? Usually, I can solve 1-2 questions fully and 3-4 questions partially(that is the whole question except the last part) with a good level of accuracy. I'm unsure if this will be sufficient as I don't know how lenient the marking is and also marks allocation to different parts of problems varies a lot. Also, for the very few candidates who are able to solve 6 problems in 2 hours-how do they do it? Is it about iq or have they practiced an insane number of qns?

Comment: @A.Goodier Also, as you suggest I often do not look at solutions and struggle with the problem for a long time(2h is probably max). However, I do not see this helping me to improve my ingenuity that much. Could you explain how that process works? Also, are there any other methods? I'm feeling a bit helpless because it feels my performance is out of my control and based somewhat on luck.

Comment: Finally, how many papers do you recommend? I've done over 15 years and have heard about diminishing returns on doing more papers. What would you say is a good number to ensure a comfortable 1?

Comment: Perhaps you could share some examples of questions where it has taken you especially long to see the trick.

Comment: @legionwhale I wanted to do that but I felt the focus of the question would shift to that. Still, an example is STEP 2 2021 Q1 part (ii). Its a trig problem and it took me a few attempts to solve it and I wasted a lot of time....you can see the questions database here:- https://www.admissionstesting.org/for-test-takers/step/preparing-for-step/

Comment: @Boson This becomes a difficult question to answer otherwise. I'm not quite sure I agree that the tricks are not similar between questions; the similarities may not be completely apparent, but they are still going to be there. Also, solving STEP questions often takes some faith; sometimes, you need to try a few different approaches (and write down quite a lot of algebra) before the possibility of a trick emerges.

Comment: @legiowhale I agree that sometimes different approaches are required. Usually, I can solve almost all problems if there is no time limit. However, with the limit in place, I often can't solve the full question(especially the final parts which are trickier and require multiple attempts)...Also could you please look at the questions I asked A. Goodier?

Comment: I unfortunately had to vote to close this question since it seems to be seeking personal advice on how to pass these STEP exams, but you would see answers in the comments regardless. From personal experience, I agree that once you get to a high-enough level of math, you'd realize that practicing these STEP exam problems would only get you so far with the toolbelt you currently have. And this is where you would need to consult outside resources for help, like learning from a new textbook or asking for help from more experienced people.

Comment: Speaking as an American (ew), I don't know how the University of Cambridge handles these exams. It seems like your main concern is passing these exams with flying colors. As someone who grew up in a US high school a few years ago where all teachers do is focus on making their students pass exams, I can assure you that just trying to pass these STEP exams won't be as beneficial as trying to learn as much math as possible. So I would set your priorities on the latter.

Comment: I downloaded one of the STEP exam packets just to see what they are like. Even if you do study your heart out for the STEP exams and you ace them, you would still have more walls to overcome during university. You would still have the difficulty of understanding the lectures, the homework, more exams, etc. I think most people would agree that university-level math is *significantly* harder than entrance exams. But this is why I advocate for learning for knowledge rather than for tests. Staying in university takes knowledge, and that's the road down the line for just studying exams.

Comment: I know from personal experience that if you study for the sake of gaining knowledge, it makes study sessions feel more meaningful and easy. But realistically speaking, no one would be able to learn all the math in the world in two months. I think the best course of action from here is to see which STEP exam problem gives you the most trouble and, assuming you know LaTeX, ask that specific question on this site on how to solve it. Almost everyone on this site is experienced enough for those questions (well, the ones with a lot of reputation points would be).

Comment: @Boson By 4 good solutions, I mean complete or close to complete - of course, the grade boundaries vary from year to year but you should be aiming to get around 70 marks in both papers. Few marks may be given for fragmentary answers so you should aim for as many complete solutions as you can. I suggest not looking at solutions too soon because solving the problems unaided will make you a stronger mathematician. The more you practise, the easier you will find it to make connections between the questions and things you have seen before.

Comment: @Accelerator These papers are by far the best available predictor of performance in the first year of Cambridge mathematics (and better than any predictor in any other subject).  Since you can only choose up to 6 out of the 12 questions (most do fewer), they reward your depth of knowledge, understanding and skill plus completeness of application.  They are elite exams built on a syllabus designed for a much broader population of school students.

Comment: @Henry do you have any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preparation for STEP Mathematics Examinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095347/preparation-for-step-mathematics-examinations)

Answer (score 1):

When I was a university student studying Mathematics I was always stressed out during tests.  But for my final Math course (Number theory), I approached it differently.  Every time the professor finished a topic, I searched for related final exam questions from all over the English-speaking world.  Some of these questions were easier than what we were required to know; some were harder.  But I did them all.  Since I had done so many questions from so many professors, I felt that there was nothing that my professor could ask on the final exam that could give me any sort of difficulty except maybe some challenging bonus question.  I was quite relaxed during the final exam and got an A+.  Perhaps you could search for exams similar to your exams but from different universities.  Best of luck!